# JavaFX change node generated by FXML to another node

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, controlsfx

I have a complicated UI defined by the fxml file. There are a lot of stock `TextField`s that I would like to change to more advanced versions (clearable text field) provided by [ControlsFX](https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx) library.

The problem:

ControlsFX uses `CustomTextField` to provide advanced features but it can only be initialized by `TextFields.createClearableTextField()` which can only be called from code.

I am looking for a way to swap `TextField`s initialized via FXML with `CustomTextField`s initialized from code so that these new controls would retain all layout properties defined in FXML.

Defining `CustomTextField` in FXML is also not helpful because by default it is useless.
`CustomTextField` gains it's features via `private static void setupClearButtonField(TextField inputField, ObjectProperty<Node> rightProperty)` which i can't call because it's private.

ControlsFX code:

```
/**
 * Creates a TextField that shows a clear button inside the TextField (on
 * the right hand side of it) when text is entered by the user.
 */
public static TextField createClearableTextField() {
    CustomTextField inputField = new CustomTextField();
    setupClearButtonField(inputField, inputField.rightProperty());
    return inputField;
}

/**
 * Creates a PasswordField that shows a clear button inside the PasswordField
 * (on the right hand side of it) when text is entered by the user.
 */
public static PasswordField createClearablePasswordField() {
    CustomPasswordField inputField = new CustomPasswordField();
    setupClearButtonField(inputField, inputField.rightProperty());
    return inputField;
}

private static void setupClearButtonField(TextField inputField, ObjectProperty<Node> rightProperty) {
    inputField.getStyleClass().add("clearable-field"); //$NON-NLS-1$

    Region clearButton = new Region();
    clearButton.getStyleClass().addAll("graphic"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    StackPane clearButtonPane = new StackPane(clearButton);
    clearButtonPane.getStyleClass().addAll("clear-button"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    clearButtonPane.setOpacity(0.0);
    clearButtonPane.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
    clearButtonPane.setOnMouseReleased(e -> inputField.clear());
    clearButtonPane.managedProperty().bind(inputField.editableProperty());
    clearButtonPane.visibleProperty().bind(inputField.editableProperty());

    rightProperty.set(clearButtonPane);

    final FadeTransition fader = new FadeTransition(FADE_DURATION, clearButtonPane);
    fader.setCycleCount(1);

    inputField.textProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
        @Override public void invalidated(Observable arg0) {
            String text = inputField.getText();
            boolean isTextEmpty = text == null || text.isEmpty();
            boolean isButtonVisible = fader.getNode().getOpacity() > 0;

            if (isTextEmpty && isButtonVisible) {
                setButtonVisible(false);
            } else if (!isTextEmpty && !isButtonVisible) {
                setButtonVisible(true);
            }
        }

        private void setButtonVisible( boolean visible ) {
            fader.setFromValue(visible? 0.0: 1.0);
            fader.setToValue(visible? 1.0: 0.0);
            fader.play();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What happens when you use the CustomTextField in place of a TextField in your code and FXML? `createClearableTextField()` returns a TextField, so it seems like formatting and placement should continue to work correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `fx:factory` as described in [Introduction to FXML](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#instance_declaration_elements).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import org.controlsfx.control.textfield.TextFields?>

<StackPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
           fx:controller="com.example.Controller">

    <TextFields fx:id="field" fx:factory="createClearableTextField"/>

</StackPane>
```

Then use it in the controller:

```
package com.example;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class Controller {

    @FXML private TextField field;

}
```

*Note: If you're using IntelliJ, it will emit an error saying:*

> *Cannot set org.controlsfx.control.textfield.TextFields to field 'field'*

*In the FXML file, but when I ran a test project everything worked properly.*

Comment: Unfortunately, it fails to load FXML file with `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException`. It tries to load `createClearableTextField()` as a static method of `javafx.scene.control.TextField`, but it exists in `org.controlsfx.control.textfield.TextFields`.

Comment: I've overcame this problem by creating `class MyTextField extends TextField` and providing `public static TextField create() { return TextFields.createClearableTextField()` }. Then I wrote `<MyTextField fx:factory="create"/>` in FXML file.

Comment: I can't reproduce that problem, even when I have both `TextField` and `TextFields` imported; I tried on JavaFX 8u202, JavaFX 11.0.2, and JavaFX 12. Are you sure you didn't just have a typo (e.g. `TextField` instead of `TextFields`)?

Comment: Can confirm, it works on JavaFX 15.0.1 with ControlsFX 11.0.3 in Intellij Community 2020.3, thank you!